# Running code after page load while using ob_implicit_flush

Tags: php, nginx, buffer, flush

I'm trying to run code after the page has finished loading while pushing content as it's ready.

Here's my current script:

```php
<?php      
ob_implicit_flush(1);
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
ignore_user_abort(1);
echo 'Hello'; // User will see this
ob_flush();
flush();
echo 'World'; // User won't see this
```

The goal is for something like this:

```php
<?php
echo '1'; // Send to user right away
sleep(1);
echo '2'; // Send to user as soon as sleep(1) is done
echo '3'; // Don't show user at all
```

At the moment it's pushing content as it's ready, but it isn't stopping the page load.